# Graphviz's executable not found

Tags: python, decision-tree, data-science

I'm trying to learn data science online and when I run a script from one of a Google video, I get this error:

```
File "/documents/testpython.py", line 547, in <module>
graph.write_pdf("iris pdf")

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydotplus/graphviz.py", line 1810, in <lambda>
prog=self.prog: self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydotplus/graphviz.py", line 1918, in write
fobj.write(self.create(prog, format))

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydotplus/graphviz.py", line 1960, in create
'GraphViz\'s executables not found')

pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

**Here is the script:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()
test_idx = [0,50,100]

train_target = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis = 0)

test_target = iris.target[test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=iris.feature_names, class_names=iris.target_names, filled=True, rounded=True, impurity=False)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris pdf")
```

If anyone has any idea, I'm not sure if the problem comes from my version of python or the libraries or anything else...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install graphviz exe from [www.graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org) and possibly add it to the PATH.